# Is there a possibility to encrypt media files uploaded in Moodle?

Tags: encryption, moodle

I've run into a problem using Moodle 3.2. I'm uploading mp3-files to be played in a quiz. I have the license to use those files for that specific purpose, but I am not the owner. Thus, I would like to ensure that nobody without a Moodle account can access these files.

However, the path to the files can be extracted from the source code and once you have the path, anybody can access the file. Is there any way to protect the file so only registered users can access it, even if they have the direct path?

Thank you so much!

All the best
Dom

EDIT: I've learned that files actually are encrypted by login - I just had the login cookie remaining in several browsers and thus was able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files served by moodleinstallation/pluginfile.php/? This would include login/permission checks